# Override Windows Color and Appearance behaviour in my WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

By default if we change any setting in this window, all installed applications  look and behaviour echo the same.

I do not want this behaviour in my WPF application. How do I do this please?

[image]

Comment: Check out this article over on CP... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

Comment: Or simply set your `WindowStyle="None"` and build your own functionality for the `Border`, `Icon`, `Title`, and `WindowState` buttons.

Comment: interesting. I will check. How about Font and Font size , B, I, Icon spacing etc?

Comment: Thanks @DeanKuga We need to Exclusively set these property to avoid these being overridden by Windows Settings. Since this is WPF application I found even my Style classes missing set these property, so the problem.